# Difference in starting order of Psukei Dezimra

Tags: tefilla, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard, pesukei-dezimra

The order of the beginning of Puskei Dezimra (weekday Shacharit for purposes of this question, although the structure for Shabbat / Yom Tov is similar with additional Tehillim) differs between Nusach Ashkenaz and Nusach Sefard

**Nusach Ashkenaz:**

- Mizmor Shir Chanukat Habayit (Psalm 30)
- Baruch She'amar
- Hodu
- Mizmor Letodah (Psalm 100)

**Nusach Sefard:**

- Hodu
- Mizmor Shir Chanukat Habayit (Psalm 30)
- Baruch She'amar
- Mizmor Letodah (Psalm 100)

Why the difference in the order?

Comment: It has to do with why you're saying hodu. According to sefard, the reason is because it was said by the *Aron Hakodesh* (see Kol Bo). According to Ashkenaz, it's part of pesukei dizimrah.

Comment: Psalm 30 has only been said in some Ashkenzi rites for just over 200 years. It's really just an addendum to Hodu in Kabbalistic Sefardi rites. Some Ashkenazim copied the Sefardim but left the rest of Hodu later on. Go figure.

Comment: Is hodu one of the shire David?

Comment: Abudarham did not say hodu

Comment: @kouty it's a song of assaf who served under David. Could very reasonably be considered just as Davidic as any other Psalm

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've heard that the Lurianic institution of Ps. 30 was for a mizmor to be recited after Hodu. According to this understanding, Ps. 100 fulfils such requirements. In those Ashkenazi communities which never adopted the recitation of Ps. 30, we don't really care either way, though

Comment: See Beit Yosef (Orach Chaim 50)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Seder Olam Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Seder_Olam_Rabbah.14.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), the first fifteen verses of Hodu were recited during the morning korban tamid service, and the last fourteen verses were recited during the afternoon korban tamid service. According to Nusach Sefard, Hodu is to be recited right after Korbanos, due to its connection with the korban tamid service.

Nusach Ashkenaz doesn't reorder Pesukei D'zimrah because the text of Hodu is general praise, and matches the rest of the section of Pesukei D'zimrah.

Comment: What's your source for the difference between Nusach Askenaz and Nusach Sefard?

Comment: I think this answer can be improved by defining what actually begins *Psukei Dezimra*. There seems to be an assumption that *Baruch She'amar* is the beginning. However, this bracha seems to be a much later addition to the tefilla, and is not mentioned in the Gemara. So, you may have to account for that fact. B"N, I'll add this detail to my question, later.

Comment: This is almost a straight quote from the Artscroll siddur. @Ploni

Comment: So why doesn't Psalm 30 also get pushed till after BSh like Hodu or the rest of the Psalms on Shabbat which match the general theme? (Don't look too hard; there is no good answer.)

Comment: @Heshy Believe it or not, I didn't get it from the ArtScroll. :) Just took a peek in and saw how similar it is.

Comment: @ezra I apologize then

Comment: @Heshy No, don't apologize... I'm considering editing and just quoting the ArtScroll; might make my answer more "authorative" somehow.